# Why is mul used and not matmul?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, recommendation-engine

why do we use

```
out = torch.mul(usr_emb, item_emb).sum()
```

instead of

```
out = torch.matmul(usr_emb, torch.transpose(item_emb))
```

when we perform matrix factorization for RecSys?

Is it used for speed or something else? Can i use second variant or first give better result?

Answer (score 0):

These are two different operators. One is the [*Hadamard product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)), or element-wise multiplication ([`torch.mul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mul.html)), while the other is the standard [*matrix multiplication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) ([`torch.matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html)).

Here is an example, given `x` as:

```
>>> x = torch.arange(9).view(3,3)

>>> x.mul(x) # same as x*x
tensor([[ 0,  1,  4],
        [ 9, 16, 25],
        [36, 49, 64]])

>>> x.matmul(x) # same as x@x
tensor([[ 15,  18,  21],
        [ 42,  54,  66],
        [ 69,  90, 111]])
```